# Show loading gif upon clicking submit button if the form fields are properly completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a piece of html/javascript code that shows a loading gif when I click a submit button for my form. The problem is, when one of the form fields is empty when I click the submit button, there is a message "please fill in this field" shown and the form is **not** actually **submitted**, but the gif shows up anyways. In such situation, I don't want my gif to show up, but I don't know how to prevent that.

Do you have any tips on how to make it work?


EDIT: here is a relevant piece of my code - HTML:

```
 <label for="username">username</label>
 <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control"
       placeholder="sampleusername" required>
 <div class="overlay">
 <div id="loading-img"></div>
 </div>
 <script>
 $("#submit").click(function () {
   $(".overlay").show();
 });
 </script>
```

And CSS:

```
#loading-img {
    background: url('loading.gif') center center no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
}

.overlay {
    background: #e9e9e9;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

I use a Bootstrap template that checks if the username field is empty and says to fill it if it is. I also use JQuery as you can see from the code.

Comment: Check if the form is valid before showing the loading gif. How you do that depends on your code, so if you'd like an example please edit the question to include it

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: Sure, I edited my question, hope it's workable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like below and hide the `overlay` whenever you require using `$(".overlay").hide();`

```
 $("#submit").click(function () {
     var isValid=$("#myform").valid();//using jquery validation
      if(isValid)
      {
          $(".overlay").show();
          event.preventDefault();
      }

     //submit the form
 );
```

Comment: The `valid()` method does not work for me. I downloaded and imported the `jquery.validate.min.js` file to my HTML from the jquery website. How should I import it to make it work?

Comment: I finally just dealt with it by copying the `jquery.validate.min.js` code into my HTML file in a `<script></script>` block and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!